# Why does my CSS not work as it should?

Tags: html, css, hover

Title says it all; my css:

```
a.menu:hover {
opacity: 1;
text-shadow: 0 0 10px white;
}
a.menu:hover ~ .dropdown {
display: block;
}

.dropdown {
display: none;
width: 50px;
height: 50px;
position: absolute;
top: 120px;
left: 120px;
background: red;
}
```

HTML:

```
<p class="left_topbar">
    <a href="http://teamcowgames.net" class="logo"><img src="css/img/logo.png"></a>
        <a href="http://teamcowgames.net/games" class="menu">Games &#9662;</a>
</p>

<div class="dropdown"></div>
```

Why does the .dropdown now get visible when hovering over the menu link?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually your `h2` is not a child of `h1` tag. You have to use `sibling operator(+)` to achieve this.

```
  h1:hover + h2{
     display: block;
  }
```

The above solution will point the next immediate sibling element. If you want to target all the elements then use the `~` operator.

```
  h1:hover ~ h2{
     display: block;
  }
```

**EDIT:**

Based on your edit, Looks like you have to change the order like below.

```
 a.menu:hover {
  opacity: 1;
  text-shadow: 0 0 10px white;
 }
 .dropdown {
   display: none;
   width: 50px;
   height: 50px;
   position: absolute;
   top: 120px;
   left: 120px;
   background: red;
  }
 a.menu:hover ~ .dropdown {
   display: block;
 }
```

**HTML**

```
 <div class="left_topbar">
      <a href="http://teamcowgames.net" class="logo"><img src="css/img/logo.png"></a>
      <a href="http://teamcowgames.net/games" class="menu">Games &#9662;</a>
      <div class="dropdown"></div>
 </div>
```

Comment: EDIT: when I tried it out on my website, it doesn't seem to work with the code I have. My code is in my main post

Comment: modified my answer with the HTML structure. check it out

Comment: Still didn't do the trick.. :/ I actually think there's something wrong with having 2 :hover on the same class

Comment: Not sure what you mean by not working. My code is working perfectly. check this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/pf7a9p43/

Comment: I don't know why it didn't work, but I just made the dropdown as a link and it worked, guess there was something with a link hovering couldn't affect a normal div

Answer (score 1):

You want to change

```
>
```

to

```
+
```

As the arrow is a descendant selector whereas the plus is a sibling selector.